# Clojure agents: rate limiting?

Tags: swing, events, clojure, agents, seesaw

Okay, so I have this small [procedural SVG editor](http://roma1n.github.com/cutndry/) in Clojure.

It has a code pane where the user creates code that generates a SVG document, and a preview pane. The preview pane is updated whenever the code changes.

Right now, on a text change event, the code gets recompiled on the UI thread (Ewwwww!) and the preview pane updated. The compilation step should instead happen asynchronously, and agents seem a good answer to that problem: ask an agent to recompile the code on an update, and pass the result to the image pane.

I have not yet used agents, and I do not know whether they work with an implicit queue, but I suspect so. In my case, I have zero interest in computing "intermediate" steps (think about fast keystrokes: if a keystroke happens before a recompilation has been started, I simply want to discard the recompilation) -- ie I want a `send` to overwrite any pending agent computation.

How do I make that happen? Any hints? Or even a code sample? Is my rambling even making sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe a problem that has more to deal with execution flow control rather than shared state management. Hence, you might want to leave STM apart for a moment and look into **futures**: they're still executed in a thread pool as agents, but instead of agents they can be stopped by calling `future-cancel`, and inspecting their status with `future-cancelled?`.

There are no strong guarantees that the thread the future is executing [can be effectively stopped](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Still, your code will be able to try to cancel the future, and move on to schedule the next recompilation.

Answer (score 2):

agents to indeed work on a queue, so each function gets the state of the agent and  produces the next state of the agent. Agents track an identity over time. this sounds like a little more than you need, **atoms are a slightly better fit for your task** and used in a very similar manner.